# SQL Create Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I'm having trouble calling a function that I have created. Any help would be most appreciated. Here is the function:

```
     CREATE FUNCTION myFunction
(
@T DECIMAL(38,14),
@R DECIMAL (38,14),
@S DECIMAL(38,14)
)
RETURNS DECIMAL(38,14)
AS
BEGIN

RETURN 

SQRT(
    ABS(
            (@T/(@R-1))-((@R/(@R-1))*(@S*@S))))
/@S

END
GO
```

I then need to use this function on a table. This is to fill the 'CV' column. This needs to work on the following columns:

```
@T Decimal (38,14) as SumSqJT
@R Decimal (38,14) as "SumObs"
@S Decimal (38,14) as "AvJT"
```

**EDIT:**

This is the function I've then used

```
Use [Neutral Month 20132014 ALL]

SELECT 
     dbo.MyFunction(SumSqJT1, SumObs, AvJT) AS FunctionResult
FROM
     Essex_Data_1314
WHERE
     SumObs > 1
```

This creates the list of figures, however I need to update column CV in table Essex_Data_1314 not just create a list of figures. How do i do that?

This has now been solved to be this:

```
Use [Neutral Month 20132014 ALL]

UPDATE
    Essex_Data_1314
SET
    CV = dbo.MyFunction(SumSqJT1, SumObs1, AvJT)
```

Note: It is important to have everything as either a DECIMAL or a NUMERIC datatype. Otherwise conversion errors occur.

Thanks for the help JohnnyBell.

Cheers.

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: I don't know how to actually execute the function.

Comment: Just to make it clear. Your function is created without any errors, but you do not know how to call it?

Comment: Yeah, the function created fine.

Comment: how did you try to call it? did you try to search on google/bing/yahoo/ msdn/ stackoverflow ?

Comment: This is the first time that I see a question where it is stated that it is unknown how to _invoke_ a function but it is known how to _create_ it...It's like producing a car and not even knowing how to turn it on.

Comment: @AlbertoSolano very true! Although I did have a go at calling it and received some similar errors to what I have now received with the option answered below.

Comment: What errors are you receiving? If they are conversion errors, I would assume you're trying to execute this on string data contained within the columns you're referencing the function with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not really sure what the problem is. Or if there is any problem. If you want to know how to call your created function, you'll need to do something like this:

```
SELECT MyFunction(@T,@R,@S)
```

Obviously replacing the @T, @R, @S with the values you like to pass through the function.

If you want to use the function on columns within a table, you can reference the column names inside the function call like so:

```
SELECT 
    MyFunction(Column1, Column2, Column3) AS FunctionResult
FROM
    MyTable
```

If you want to update a column with these results, you can easily do this with an UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE
    MyTable
SET
    FunctionResult = MyFunction(Column1,Column2,Column3)
```

Thanks.

Comment: I need to use the function on a whole table, not just a few values. Is that possible?

Comment: How do I use this function to update a column and not just create a list of figures? Thanks.

Comment: I'll edit my answer again, check in a few minutes :)

Comment: i've fixed all the conversion errors and now have created the same answers as in Excel :). Thanks fo ryour help.